# How to use LWRP on in AWS OpsWorks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nfs, chef, opsworks

**Ohai,**

ist there a way to use LWRP for Chef on AWS OpsWorks? How else would I execute this:

```
nfs_export "/exports" do
  network '10.0.0.0/8'
  writeable false 
  sync true
  options ['no_root_squash']
end
```

This is the cookbook this is from:

https://github.com/atomic-penguin/cookbook-nfs

I would like to add an export, but I can't like that. Also, I would like to create an rc.local entry to mount the exports on the nodes - with chef would be ideal for better deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this exactly as you would if you were dealing with a normal Chef implementation. If you create a wrapper cookbook, and add a dependency on the NFS cookbook in your cookbook's metadata.rb, the `nfs_export` resource will be available to use in your wrapper cookbook's default recipe.

To add custom recipes from a Git repository, to an OpsWorks stack, you need to configure the stack to pull the cookbooks in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable.html

So, for example, you create a git repository with the following structure:

`cookbooks -> freshmelon-nfs --> metadata.rb
                             |-> recipes -> default.rb`

So that's a cookbooks folder in your repository, where you add a folder for each custom cookbook. The bare bones layout for a cookbook is a `metadata.rb` in your custom cookbook (freshmelon-nfs in this example) which describes the cookbook, and a recipes folder, which contains one ruby file for each recipe, the default is called default.rb.

As an example metadata.rb

`name             'afreshmelon-nfs'
maintainer       'Your Name'
maintainer_email 'your@email'
license          'MIT'
description      'NFS Wrapper'
long_description 'Configures NFS for aFreshMelon'
version          '0.1'
depends      'nfs'`

An example default.rb

`nfs_export "/exports" do
  network '10.0.0.0/8'
  writeable false 
  sync true
  options ['no_root_squash']
end`

Then you can call afreshmelon-nfs::default in your lifecycle (Setup, Configure, Install) events in the Layer configuration of your OpsWorks stack.

You can also then create a `client.rb` in your recipes folder, which you can include in the layter configuration for your clients, to mount the export.

`mount "/mnt/nfs" do
  device "yourserver:/exports"
  fstype "nfs"
  options "rw"
  action [:mount, :enable]
end`

That will add the NFS mount to your fstab, and it will be mounted on boot along with other filesystems.